# KnockoutJs + jquery: how to check if all radio buttons in a div are selected

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

my html looks like this

the above code has been generated based on **No of patient text** box in previos page 
i want to make sure that the user will select a value for each one of them before he submits the form, how can i check that all radio buttons inside my table has a value checked?

Thank you

Comment: Note that all the radio buttons have the same `name` attributes, this means that only one radio button can be selected.

Comment: Yes, i am facing the same issue in KnockOut Js, In the previous screen user add the No Of Patients= 5 , user needs to fill the five patient details. How i will resolve the problem in Knockout + Jquery validations

Answer (score 0):

```
$(table).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length
```

will give you the total no. of check box selected in table

Answer (score 0):

Asking the view directly is not a nice approach; One of the reasons to use the View/View Model architecture is to minimize this kind of direct DOM manipulation. You want to ask your model this question.

You didn't post much code, do you have an array of ViewModels stored in some parent model for all these radio buttons ? If yes, you can use something like

```
options.every(function(model) {return model.Gender});
```